# How can we show these two relations?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I want to show that $$\frac{p_n}{p_{n-1}}=[a_n, \ a_{n-1}, \ \ldots , \ a_1, \ a_0] 
\ \ \ (n\geq 1)$$ and that $$p_nq_{n-3}-q_np_{n-3}=(-1)^{n-1}(a_na_{n-1}+1)$$ but I don't really have an idea how to start.

Could you give me a hint?

Comment: Induction on $n$?

Comment: $p_n$ is the $n$th prime, isn't it? What exactly is $q_n$ ? @MisterRiemann

Comment: In the context of continued fractions, $p_n$ and $q_n$ are respectively the numerator and the denominator of the $n$-th convergent $C_n$.

Comment: Let us know if you need further hints.

Comment: Base Case: For $n=1$ we have $\frac{p_1}{p_0}=\frac{a_1a_0+1}{1}=a_1a_0+1$. Is this equal to $[a_1, a_0]$ ?
$$$$ 
Inductive Hypothesis: We suppose that the statement holds for some $n$, i.e. $\frac{p_n}{p_{n-1}}=[a_n, \ a_{n-1}, \ \ldots , \ a_1, \ a_0]$. 
$$$$ 
Inductive Step: We want to show that it holds for $n+1$: $$\frac{p_{n+1}}{p_n}=\frac{a_{n+1}p_{n}+p_{n-1}}{p_n}=a_{n+1}+\frac{p_{n-1}}{p_n}=a_{n+1}+\frac{1}{\frac{p_n}{p_{n-1}}}$$ Is this correct so far? @MisterRiemann

Comment: The base case should read $$ \frac{p_1}{p_0} = \frac{a_1p_0+p_{-1}}{p_0} = a_1 + \frac{1}{a_0} = [a_1; a_0]. $$ The rest looks great!

Comment: Then we have $$\frac{p_{n+1}}{p_n}=a_{n+1}+\frac{1}{\frac{p_n}{p_{n-1}}}=a_{n+1}+\frac{1}{[a_n, \ a_{n-1}, \ \ldots , \ a_1, \ a_0]}$$ which is equal to $[a_{n+1}, \ a_n, \ a_{n-1}, \ \ldots , \ a_1, \ a_0]$, or not? @MisterRiemann

Comment: Yes! And then just apply the axiom of induction and you're done!

Comment: I see!! For the second part, to show that $p_nq_{n-3}-q_np_{n-3}=(-1)^{n-1}(a_na_{n-1}+1)$ do we apply again induction? @MisterRiemann

Answer (score 0):

**Hint for the second question!!**

Use that $p_{n-3}=p_{n-1}-a_{n-1}p_{n-2}$ and $q_{n-3}=q_{n-1}-a_{n-1}q_{n-2}$.

Doing some math you will get 
$(p_{n}q_{n-1} - q_{n}p_{n-1}) + a_{n-1} ( q_{n}p_{n-2} - p_{n}q_{n-2} ) $

Use induction for the 2 brackets.